# How to get all the categories including the child as an object in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to get the categories in hierarchical structure. All i know is wp_dropdown_categories(), but this method returns the categories with the html elements. is there any method in Wordpress to get the categories & child as a php object or do i need to write own function to fetch categories recursively ? i need to modify the select tags & options too.

Here is what i have done so far .

```
$themesArgs = array(
   'hide_empty' => 0,
   'hierarchical'=> 1,
   'exclude'=> '',
   'echo'=> 0,
   'name'=>'themes',
   'id'=>'themes',
   'child_of'=>3,   
); 

$allCats = $cat_dropdown = preg_replace( 
    '^' . preg_quote( '<select ' ) . '^', 
    '<select multiple placeholder="Themes" ', 
    wp_dropdown_categories($themesArgs)
);

print_r($allCats);
```

im new to Wordpress development.thanks in advance

Comment: `get_categories()` is probably what you're after

Comment: @naththedeveloper, so i need to recursively call this method . ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [wp_list_categories](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/) to get all categories. If you need to output them in a special format, use a custom [Walker](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/walker_category/).

```
class MyCustomWalker extends Walker_Category {
// override functions as needed
}

wp_list_categories(array("option" => "value", "walker" => new MyCustomWalker));
```

Comment: That seems interesting.. let me check this out.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code this is working fine

```
$category = get_the_category(get_the_ID());
$catid=$category[0]->category_parent;
if($catid==0){
  $catid=$category[0]->cat_ID;
}
$categories = get_categories('child_of='.intval($catid));                    
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    if ($category->parent ==$catid):
        echo '<span class="category"><a href="">'.$category->cat_name.'</a></span>';
        $subcategories=  get_categories('child_of='.intval($category->cat_ID));
        foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory) {
            echo '<span class="subcategory" style="padding-left:12px">';
            echo '<a href="">'.$subcategory->cat_name.'</a></span>';
        }
    endif;
}
```

Comment: @Hussain Ahmed Thanks for the reply, i believe that there is no built-in function to achieve this. The above code will only list the categories, i need the hierarchical structure.

Comment: if category have no post then category will not show. Check above code after assign post on those category, definitely category will show in hierarchical structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php

  $taxonomy     = 'product_cat';
  $orderby      = 'name';  
  $show_count   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
  $pad_counts   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
  $hierarchical = 1;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no  
  $title        = '';  
  $empty        = 0;

  $args = array(
         'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
         'orderby'      => $orderby,
         'show_count'   => $show_count,
         'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
         'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
         'title_li'     => $title,
         'hide_empty'   => $empty
  );
 $all_categories = get_categories( $args );
 foreach ($all_categories as $cat) {
    if($cat->category_parent == 0) {
        $category_id = $cat->term_id;       
        echo '<br /><a href="'. get_term_link($cat->slug, 'product_cat') .'">'. $cat->name .'</a>';

        $args2 = array(
                'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
                'child_of'     => 0,
                'parent'       => $category_id,
                'orderby'      => $orderby,
                'show_count'   => $show_count,
                'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
                'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
                'title_li'     => $title,
                'hide_empty'   => $empty
        );
        $sub_cats = get_categories( $args2 );
        if($sub_cats) {
            foreach($sub_cats as $sub_category) {
                echo  $sub_category->name ;
            }   
        }
    }       
}
?>
```

This will list all the top level categories and subcategories under them hierarchically. do not use the inner query if you just want to display the top level categories. Style it as you like.